# construct string union type from keys of custom type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

How can I construct a string union type in TypeScript that is based on the keys of a custom type? Of course it would only work if they're all strings.

Let's say I have this:

```
type MyFields {
  name: string
  email: string
  password: string
}
```

How could I generate something like that:

```
type MyFieldsKeys = 'name' | 'email' | 'password'
```

Does such a feature exist?

It'a kind of the opposite of what [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#example-3) does - I could for instance generate `MyFields` from `MyfieldsKeys` with `Record` by doing `MyFields = Record<MyFieldsKeys, string>`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) to produce a string or numeric literal union of keys.

```
type MyFields = {
  name: string
  email: string
  password: string
}

type MyfieldsKeys = keyof MyFields;
```